# Should Poller throw or handle a exception while reading from SQS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, listener, amazon-sqs

I am writing a custom java SQS Poller to read from Amazon SQS and do some operation on messages. It is a multithreaded application which will spawn a fixed pool of threads and each thread will listen to the SQS.

Now, I have a doubt in one of the aspect of the implementation that, say while receiving or deleting messages from SQS, I got some exception, should I throw the exception and exits that thread from there? Or should I just catch the exception without throwing it and retry to receive the message again? In 2nd case, to know that it is not working properly, I will probably publish some metrics on which I could create a alarm so that I would come to know if this is happening a lot.

Which way is the suggested one or better practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have problem with communication to SQS you should catch the exception where it occurs and log it. You can have some retry policy, that's up tu you. Log these problems then you can more precisely address the problem.

I wouldn't go out from the thread that created the exception to catch it somwhere else. In my opiniom it should be served in place where it occured. I would log every retry and  final message if the retry procedure would fail.

Comment: Probably also want a little sleep in there somewhere after an exception so you don't go into a spin loop and get really aggressive on the retries in cases where the error is not transient.